# start activity after ending the previous one

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android application and it asks some questions before the program actually starts. The questions are Activity.
so:

```
 Intent dateContactIntent;
 Intent intervalIntent;
 Intent intervalMiercuri;

 dateContactIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
 startActivityForResult(dateContactIntent, DATE_CONTACT_ACTIVITY);

 intervalIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
 startActivityForResult(intervalIntent, RETRY_TIME_ACTIVITY);

 intervalMiercuri = new Intent(this, C.class);
 startActivityForResult(intervalMiercuri, ALEGERE_MIERCURI_ACTIVITY);
```

So, instead asking me 3 questions A, then B, then C it asks in the following order: C, B, A.

So, the idea is: how do I start another activity after the previous one has ended?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A:

```
if(answered){
  Intent int = new Intent(this, b.class);
  startforResultActivity(int);
finish();
}
```

In B:

```
if(...)
  .... c.class)
  ....
  finish();
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

First launch your A

```
dateContactIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
startActivityForResult(dateContactIntent, DATE_CONTACT_ACTIVITY);
```

Add this to `onActivityResult`

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, ...) {
    if (requestCode == DATE_CONTACT_ACTIVITY) {
        intervalIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(intervalIntent, RETRY_TIME_ACTIVITY);
    } else if (requestCode == RETRY_TIME_ACTIVITY) {
        intervalMiercuri = new Intent(this, C.class);
        startActivityForResult(intervalMiercuri, ALEGERE_MIERCURI_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

If you do not have a main activity that handles everything, then you would have to launch B from inside activity A, and launch C from inside activity B.